# Python programmin: Not entering the If loop

Tags: python

I want to know why my program isn't entering the if condition.

```
import re

message="b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8816\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36\r\nReferer: http://localhost:8816/\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n'"
print(message)

filename1=re.search(r'/[^H]*',message).group()

a="/"
a=str(a)
print(filename1)
if filename1 == a:
    filename2='/Users/ankushverma/Desktop/www/index.html'
    print(filename2)
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: filename1 is "/" i.e. the output from re.search which is equal to "a" defined. Then why it is not entering the IF loop and printing filename2.  I am just getting output till print(filename1)

Answer (score 2):

Because `filename1` is "/ ". That is, your regex is capturing the space after the slash as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
filename1=re.search(r'/[^H]*',message).group().strip()
```

.strip() removes leading and trailing whitespace which was causing the comparison to return false.

Comment: Thanks :-) it worked :-)